# Google Play Store: release new version only for specified countries

Tags: android, google-play, release

We already have App in Play Store and want to release a new version to test only in 2 specific countries. I'm searching for the right way to do it.
According to the [document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en) if I have production release I need to create Beta release track and target it for countries needed. Will users of that countries see it as regular App? Or I can create another production release and point it to my countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a production with staging rollout with 99.9% value and chose the two countries you want to test.

Comment: won't it shadow my current release with old version that works for the whole world?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think it will not shadow the old version. Anyway. You can try and if the it did not do what it suppose to do, you can halt the release

Comment: @zalexei was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Comment: cannot tell for now. I'm still looking for evidences that it will work and now shadow. Cannot try it without knowing it for 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create another production release and point it to your target countries?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).